# LSTM dimension for time series

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, lstm

I read that LSTM needs a 3D input. I have time-series data containing 2000 rows and 5 columns. How does my data convert into the input  [samples, time steps, features]? Thank you

Comment: LSTM can take 1d input.  There are examples for 2d surface in 3d made by arrays of LSTM.  It is for time-series, but outside of that, no explicit constraints on dimensionality.

Comment: Okay thank you i will retry